# Can we extend this pair of inequalities to a larger domain?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I saw this pair of inequalities in some book about calculus:

$1^k+2^k+...(n-1)^k< \dfrac {n^{k+1}}{k+1}<1^k+2^k+...+n^k$

valid for every integer $n\geq1$ and every integer $k\geq1$ and started to think would this inequality be still true if we view $k$ not as integer $\geq1$ but as real number $\geq1$.

So the question is:

> Do we have $1^x+2^x+...+(n-1)^x< \dfrac {n^{x+1}}{x+1}<1^x+2^x+...+n^x$ for every real $x \geq1$?

Also, if there is some general enough theory or subtheory about when we can and cannot do things like this done in the question, tell me something about it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the function given by:
$$f:t\mapsto t^x$$
is increasing for $x\geq1$.
Then,
$$n^x\le\int_n^{n+1}t^xdt\le(n+1)^x$$
Let $S_N=\sum_{n=0}^Nn^x$, we have:
$$S_N\le\int_0^{N+1}t^xdt\le S_{N+1}$$
Therefore, for all real $x\geq1$,
$$S_N\le \frac {(N+1)^{x+1}}{x+1}\le S_{N+1}$$
This method is called [integral test](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparaison_s%C3%A9rie-int%C3%A9grale).

Comment: In fact, the conclusion is true for all $x\geq0$. Same proving.